# How to link to another user in Django template

Tags: django, templates, hyperlink, model, slug

I want to link to another user to show for example their public activities.

But I don't know how to link it via template.

This is my user profile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
location = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='Tehran')
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True, default="/user_image/user_default.png")
slug = models.SlugField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.user)
    super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

# Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username


User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

But I cant use `slug` because its not defined for the user profile before the users complete their profiles.

Please help me to find something like `slug` for using in template to link to the other users like this:

```
<a href="{% url "index" user.profile.slug %}">{{ user.profile.name }}</a>
```

Comment: if slug is not defined before user complete his profile, then what's the purpose of link ?

Comment: you can use id instead.  <a href="{% url "index" user.profile.id %}">{{ user.profile.name }}</a>

Comment: Thats exactly my problem. Can I use the user directly instead of using the 'user profile'? For example how can I add an slug to the user model directly?

Comment: i suggest you first follow some simple django tutorials. otherwise you would be in trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code the slug field gets generated every time the user is saved. As it is though its not recommended to be used as a user identifier because 2 users with the same username will get the same slug.

It is recommended to use ids for now until you find a way to prevent duplicate slug names.

The:

```
 {% url "index" user.profile.slug %}
```

can be used once you have a url that accepts the slug parameter like:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.index, name='index')
```

where on the views.index view call you can do something like:

```
user = User.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

to get the user with the associated slug

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there any way to make slug field for the user.name itself?